# Remove file extension on url

Tags: php, .htaccess

Good day!
Got a lot of questions here but i guess i can't ask it all at once so i'll start with the problem i am facing now.
So, I am new to .htaccess and I don't know how or if it is possible to remove the file extensions on url, like for example I am accessing my home page in this url "www.sniper.com/home.php", so the question is clear. Is it really possible to use .htaccess to remove the file extension so that when you are at homepage the url will look just like "www.sniper.com/home" ?

Comment: can you give me a link then? I really don't know how to search for this kind of topic but thanks anyways..

Answer (score 0):

To remove .php extension

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: for more check here http://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/

Comment: I have use this answer and i found a bug on it, my error 403 or forbidden error does not work anymore.I have use `option all -indexes` and when i open the css folder it should show my error 403 but instead it shows the 404 error page which was not intended for it.